# What is this called, and how would I use it for a lockdown command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So, for example. If I was making a loop command for a music bot, I would use something like this in the code;

```
serverQueue.loop = !serverQueue.loop

msg.channel.send(`Queue Loop ${serverQueue.loop ? `**Enabled**` : `**Disabled**`}!`)
```

etc...

But, what exactly is

```
"${serverQueue.loop ? `**Enabled**` : `**Disabled**`}"
```

called. I know how it works I just don't know the exact name for what the "?" part is called.

With that being said, how would I use this in a different type of command for example a lock down command. I want to have the `"? **Enabled** : **Disabled**"` part in the code, so I don't have to do for example "!lockdown enable" or "!lockdown disable", etc. I can't figure out how to use it it my lockdown code, because it returns with the same message "Lockdown has been **Enabled**" every time I use the command, even though I have code to something similar as the code up above. Here is an example of my code of what I'm trying to do, and maybe it would explain it better.

```
var Discord = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
    names: ['lockdown'],
    description: "Locks/Unlocks all the channels",
    execute: async function execute(client, msg, args) {

        var everyoneRole = msg.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "@everyone")

        if(!msg.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) {
            return msg.reply("You do not have permission to use this command!")
        } else {
            var toggle
            toggle = !toggle
            msg.channel.send(`Lockdown has been ${toggle ? `**Enabled**` : `**Disabled**`} by ${msg.author}!`)
            if(toggle) {
                msg.guild.channels.cache.forEach(channel => {
                    channel.updateOverwrite(everyoneRole.id, {
                        SEND_MESSAGES: false,
                        VIEW_CHANNEL: false,
                        READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY: false
                    })
                })
            } else {
                msg.guild.channels.cache.forEach(channel => {
                    channel.updateOverwrite(everyoneRole.id, {
                        SEND_MESSAGES: true,
                        VIEW_CHANNEL: true,
                        READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY: true
                    })
                }) 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's called a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Comment: Not sure why the question is closed because that isn't my only question?

Comment: `toggle` is always truthy because you're defining it as undefined with `var toggle` then setting it to true with `toggle = !toggle`.

Comment: And how would I change that.

Comment: By.. defining it with a non-undefined value? I can't tell you what `toggle` is supposed to be; only you know that.

Comment: Could you give me an example.

Comment: `toggle = false` versus `toggle = true`

Comment: Ah, so like would I use var toggle = true? And toggle = !toggle would change toggle to toggle = false, etc?

Comment: `toggle = !toggle` is not proper use of the logical Not operator.  You need to figure out how you want the bot to figure whether to toggle true or false and how the user inputs such, and go from there.

Comment: So if I want the command to be only !lockdown, and nothing else.. How would I do that?

Comment: I know how to make the command work with !lockdown {args} but I don't want the command to be !lockdown enable or !lockdown disable. I want it only to be "!lockdown"

Comment: Then you'll have to hoist a variable onto your client object that keeps track of the current value. *!toggle is a valid way to invert the value*